# Fading slides across one another in a Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, transition, fade

I've managed to shoehorn a working Bootstrap 4 carousel into my page, although I don't know how (or if) it might be possible to get the current slide to fade out with the next slide already visible in order to eliminate the empty stage that's currently displaying between slides.

I don't fully understand the workings of the CSS that this currently uses - what I had thought was needed would be to have the current slide transition to 0, or the next slide to transition to 1, but I cannot envisage a simple method of doing so.

I've managed to get a page with this carousel up here:

http://www.minelands.com/portfolio/carousel.html

This is the HTML I'm using:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="active item"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/portfolio/1140x600-01.png" alt=""></div>
<div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/portfolio/1140x600-02.png" alt=""></div>
<div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/portfolio/1140x600-03.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
</div>
```

And here is the styling:

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
transition-property: opacity;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item, .active.left, .active.right {
opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active, .next.left, .prev.right {
opacity: 0;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next, .prev, .active.left, .active.right {
left: 0;
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

I can provide any other information required if this proves incomplete.

Comment: Are you using the latest 4.x alpha 6? The markup seems to be different that typical carousel

Comment: i believe so, yes. the markup might be a bit different as i gave up on the vanilla carousel that bootstrap themselves publish, i couldn't get it functioning. At this point, i was hoping to modify the CSS alone if it's possible.

Comment: Alpha 6 uses `carousel-item` instead of `item`

Comment: If i swap `.item` out for `.carousel-item` in HTML and CSS, the element no longer works. i believe the version in use here is still using `.item`